# Why wont blender export my texture to a glb

Tags: texturing

im curious as to why whenever I export my session with a texture to glb the texture for 2 parts arent translated and are just "white" on the export. Any information and help is greatly appreciated. [.blend is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EakOzNVBBW4BqpFxD5r_fLn4D9pCVhER/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The exporter expects your material node graph to look a certain way. See the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). If you don't follow what that exporter expects it won't export.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @scurest I think that's the answer. You could have posted it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.